# curl execution returns empty in php

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to execute a url

```
$ch1 = curl_init();

    if (!$ch1) die("Couldn't initialize a cURL handle");

$headerinfo = apache_request_headers();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $returnurl);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $headerinfo['User-Agent']);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,1*60);
$result = curl_exec($ch1);
    $responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch1, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch1);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($httpCode);
    echo "</pre>";
echo "result".$result;
    echo "responseCode".$responseCode;
    echo "curlError".curl_error($ch1);
```

While executing in browser i'm getting xml displayed. but in curl execution i'm getting response as empty. what could be the reason.

Comment: there is no error and response code is 200

Comment: @ Arasu: Have checked the source code of that page?

Comment: The url in browser returns prints an xml

Comment: how can i check curl is executing the url.

Comment: @Arasu: Check the source of the page that you execute this script. May be the xml will be shown in source.

Answer (score 0):

U forgot to return the result.

```
$result = curl_exec($ch1);
return $result; // RETURN OR ECHO RESULT.
```

Comment: how about instantiating a new XML object eg: `$response = new SimpleXMLElement($result); return $response;`

Comment: i'm not going to anything with the result. i will update the db with the responsexml

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = curl_exec($ch1); 
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch1, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($httpCode);
echo "</pre>";
echo $result;
```

Try this and get the information about the transfer. From this header information you can solve this.

Comment: I changed but still returns empty

Comment: means there is no data on that `url`

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your response using  html tag. I think that's the only way you can see xml response in browsers.

```
    echo "<xmp>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</xmp>";
```